# Getting the itemtemplate set of a collectionview through a bindable property of a custom control

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

I have been trying different ways to get this working but it just does not. I am developing a custom control in .NET MAUI. the custom control has an embedded collectionview. I am setting the content itemtemplate of the collection view using a bindable property of the same control but it just work out when I set the itemtemplate content via XAML through the bindable property. I verified the bindings and they all work, meaning the bindable property works but the itemtemplate just would not have it using XAML. I tried setting the item template via code behind and it worked fine but obviously I would rather do it via XAML as I want the user of the custom control to personalize it via XAML.

All bindings work and verified these by debugging

Please find the code of the custom control below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout x:Name="DataGridControl" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PensionApp.CustomUIControls.DataGrid"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PensionApp.CustomUIControls"
             HeightRequest="500"
             WidthRequest="500"
             Orientation="Vertical">
    <CollectionView 
             x:Name="Datagrid_collection_view"
             ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionToDisplay ,Source={x:Reference DataGridControl}}">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <ContentView Content="{Binding CustomContentTemplate, Source={x:Reference DataGridControl}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

and below is the code behind of the custom control

```
namespace PensionApp.CustomUIControls 
{ 
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;
using PensionApp;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
    public partial class DataGrid : StackLayout
    {
        public DataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty CollectionToDisplayProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(CollectionToDisplay),
            returnType: typeof(ObservableCollection<Object>),
            defaultValue: null,
            declaringType: typeof(DataGrid),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: OnCollectionToDisplayChanged
            );
        public ObservableCollection<Object> CollectionToDisplay
        {
            get => (ObservableCollection<Object>)GetValue(CollectionToDisplayProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(CollectionToDisplayProperty, (ObservableCollection<Object>)value);
            }
        }
        private static void OnCollectionToDisplayChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var DataGridControlInstance = (DataGrid)bindable;
            DataGridControlInstance.Datagrid_collection_view.ItemsSource = (ObservableCollection<object>)newValue;
        }
        
        public static readonly BindableProperty CustomContentTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(CustomContentTemplate),
            returnType: typeof(View),
            defaultValue: null,
            declaringType: typeof(DataGrid),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
            propertyChanged: OnCustomContentTemplateChanged
            );
        public View CustomContentTemplate
        {
            get => (View)GetValue(CustomContentTemplateProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(CustomContentTemplateProperty, (View)value);
            }
        }
        private static void OnCustomContentTemplateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {  
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is the code of the MainPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PensionApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PensionApp.CustomUIControls"
             x:Name="MainPageInstance">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <controls:DataGrid  CollectionToDisplay="{Binding  CollectionToPass,Source={x:Reference MainPageInstance}}">
                <controls:DataGrid.CustomContentTemplate>

                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto" HeightRequest="20">
                        <Entry Text="achnou" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Entry>
                        <Entry Text="male" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Entry>
                    </Grid>
                </controls:DataGrid.CustomContentTemplate>
            </controls:DataGrid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

and the code behind of the mainpage

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PensionApp;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;
    public ObservableCollection<Object> CollectionToPass { get; set;}
    public MainPage()
    {
        CollectionToPass = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
        CollectionToPass.Add(new Somedataexemple("XXXX", "XXXXX"));
        CollectionToPass.Add(new Somedataexemple("YYYYY", "YYYYY"));
        CollectionToPass.Add(new Somedataexemple("ZZZZZ", "ZZZZ"));
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class Somedataexemple : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public Somedataexemple(String first, string last)
    {
        First_Name = first;
        Last_Name = last;
    }
    private string first_Name;
    private string last_Name;
    public string First_Name
    {
        get => first_Name;
        set{first_Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(First_Name));}
    }
    public string Last_Name 
    {
        get => last_Name;
        set{last_Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Last_Name));}
    }
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));}
}
```

Comment: The reason why I know the binding works is because the CollectionToDisplayProperty shows the 3 items I have added in the MainPage and the reason why I know the binding works for the CustomContentTemplateProperty is because when I put another tag to display a content view in collectionview.Header, everything works

Comment: I tested your code on my side. It seems the `DataGrid` is shown in the MainPage as I set the background color of the DataGrid to Red and it is there when loading the page. So, the key is that the `DataGrid` can't display the data as you set in code behind.